# i am getting this error. "Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///Screenshot%20(2).png"

Tags: flutter, api

i am getting data from backend but image is not fetched, it cause error Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///Screenshot%20(2).png. the images from backend does not come in frontend ui but all the other data is displayed
my code is this for api

````
  List<RentalRoom> parseRooms(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<RentalRoom>((json) => RentalRoom.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
  Future<List<RentalRoom>> getRooms() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return List<RentalRoom>.from(jsonData.map((x) => RentalRoom.fromJson(x)));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load rooms');
    }
  }
class Config {
  static const String apiURL = '192.168.56.1:3001';
  static const String roomAPI = "/newapiroom/getrooms";
}
for image
 child: Image. Network(rooms[index].images![index],
fit: BoxFit.cover, ),    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try Image.file instead of Image.Network:

```
Image.file(File(rooms[index].images![index])),
```

Comment: i tried it but its not working

Comment: i cause the same error? ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///Screenshot%20(2).png?